# Let Σ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}. How many strings of length 3 or less are there over Σ?

Tags: finite-automata, automata

I Thought this would be a permutation question, but the answer 400 is not right. I also tried combination and that was also wrong. Is this a vector cross product question? If so how do I start it?

Comment: 1 + 8 + 56 + 336 =  401? Oh since it says 3 or less is picking 0 characters still a single solution? I tried this, it is also not the answer

Comment: Oops my previous comment was a bit off. It is permutations but you need to allow for repetition. So that would be `1 + 8 + 8*8 + 8*8*8`. As for string length 0 I don't know if the question is counting that or not. It's ambiguous.

Comment: Ah Ok that was my second guess but I forgot the string length 0

Comment: It's not a permutation question, and it's not a combination question, and it sure as heck isn't a vector cross product question. Like most questions in mathematics, it's a use-your-brain question. If you can't answer it right away, answer a simpler question where you can just write down all the strings, such as, let the language be $\{\,1,2\,\}$. How many strings of (say) length 3? Write 'em down! 111, 112, 121, 122, 211, 212, 221, 222. Count 'em up! Think about how you could have gotten that number without writing them all down. Then return to the original question. Don't grab; think!